# How to squash the last N commits into a single commit in git?

Tags: git, squash

I actually want to squash around **5-6** commits in a single commit. What is the best option I have in this case?

Comment: I would do `git rebase -i HEAD~6` and mark the commits as `squash` or `fixup`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+squash+last+commits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the most recent commit checked out, do a soft reset to your desired parent commit. If the commits are linear, The parent of the last `N` commits is `HEAD~N`. For example, to combine the last five commits:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~5
```

Optionally, make sure you've got the right changes with `git status` or `git diff`.

Then create the new commit:

```
git commit -m 'five combined commits in one'
```